# What are some good sources for understanding about the Kleevauks?

Tags: folklore, fairies

Has anyone else heard of the Kleevauks? I've heard a myth about a separate fay being created by the Elementals. Supposedly to help keep nature and magic balanced. I heard that these Kleevauks were supposed to be deities of the fay. I haven't been able to find any mention of the Kleevauks online or in books. I could be spelling it wrong. Any body else heard of this? If so, do you have any text or website sources?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but you're going to have to give us a bit more to work with. At a bare minimum, name (or tag) the mythological tradition you think this is from, and also name the source that "you heard" from about "deities of the fay".

Comment: There appear to be zero usable references to "Kleevauks" online. Are you sure the spelling is correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's just it. It's an old story from my aunt. The stories she would tell were about these creatures that somehow were a warp in time themselves, neither physical nor spiritual but a balance of both. They were fay that would appear before a great disaster, magical or natural, and would intervention in whatever way necessary depending on where balance was needed.

Comment: What is your aunt's cultural heritage?  (That might help identify the proper spelling of "Kleevauk", which may be incorrect in that, as Yannis notes, search of that spelling yields no usable results.  ([DeviantArt](https://juju772.deviantart.com/art/A-guide-to-the-Fay-686897991) is the only reference I found, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have a basis in san oral tradition.

Comment: @justme could you edit your question and add some detailed descriptions of your aunt's stories?